# Twig & PHP ActiveRecord - Cannot access field from join table

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig, phpactiverecord

I cannot access joined table with PHPActiveRecord/Twig. Here is simplified code. It has two models (Code and User), and each code belongs to one user, so I want to list codes with the name of code's author.

### php

```
// model
class Code extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('user'),
    );
}

class User extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $has_many = array(
        array('code'),
    );
}


// controller
$codes = Code::all(array('include' => 'user'));
var_dump($codes);      //-> successfully displayed codes list and their authors

$this->twig->display('codelist.twig', $codes);
```

### template.twig

```
{% for code in codes %}
{{ code.name }}        //-> successfully displayed code's name
{{ code.user.name }}   //-> failed to output user's name with error
{% endfor %}
// error:
// An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Call to undefined method: user") in "inc/template.twig" at line **.
```

I saw this page:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html

> Implementation
>
> For convenience sake foo.bar does the following things on the PHP
> layer:
>
> check if foo is an array and bar a valid element; if not, and if foo
> is an object, check that bar is a valid property; if not, and if foo
> is an object, check that bar is a valid method (even if bar is the
> constructor - use __construct() instead); if not, and if foo is an
> object, check that getBar is a valid method; if not, and if foo is an
> object, check that isBar is a valid method; if not, return a null
> value. foo['bar'] on the other hand only works with PHP arrays:
>
> check if foo is an array and bar a valid element; if not, return a
> null value.

Although I can access user attribute via $codes[0]->user, why can't I access user attribute in twig templates file?

Comment: Can you check this issue: https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord/issues/156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to greut, I solved the problem. I replaced function __isset in lib/Model.php in PHPActiveRecord.

```
/**
 * Determines if an attribute exists for this {@link Model}.
 *
 * @param string $attribute_name
 * @return boolean
 */
public function __isset($name)
    {
        // check for getter
        if (method_exists($this, "get_$name"))
        {
            $name = "get_$name";
            $value = $this->$name();
            return $value;
        }

        return $this->read_attribute($name);
    }
```

https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord/issues/156